# how to highlight certain words using jquery css

Tags: jquery

How can I highlight certain words as I type it in the form? The word that I want to highlight is:

```
hello world. Things is fine.
```

I have tried the code below but cannot get it to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .highlight {
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $target = $('#theWord'),
        t = ''
        
      $('#theWord1').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which !== 0) {
          t += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
          var text = $target.text(),
            pos = text.search('hello world. Things is fine.');
          if (pos > -1) {
            $target.html(text.substring(0, pos) + '<span class="highlight">' + t +
              '</span>' + text.substring(pos + t.length));
          } else {
            $target.text(text);
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>


  <div id="theWord">hello world. Things is fine.</div>

  <body>
    <div id="testDocument">
      <input type="text" id="theWord1">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help. You can change this according to your usage.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#typeText').on('keyup', function () {

            let text = $('#displayText').text();
            const searchString = $(this).val();
            const index = text.search(searchString);
            const end = index + searchString.length;

            let newString = text; // if text not found
            if (index > -1)
                newString = text.substring(0, index) + '<span class="highlight">' + text.substring(index, end) + '</span>' + text.substring(end, text.length);

            $(displayText).html(newString);
        })
    });
```

```css
.highlight {
        background: black;
        color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
    <div id="displayText">Hello world.</div>
    <input type="text" id="typeText" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I want all the words in this div `<div id="theWord">hello world. Things is fine.</div>` to be highlighted in a yellow  color as I type its word equivalents in a form input